# What is the symbol above this note?

Tags: notation, sheet-music

What does the following symbol mean?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpFtA.jpg]

Comment: I can barely read music, but I think that indicated a down-bow on a stringed instrument

Comment: Please add the instrument involved to your question. That will help for others who have the same question.

Comment: This might be of interest, from a few years back: https://music.stackexchange.com/q/20154/9198

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a "down bow" symbol. It means that the note should be played by drawing the bow from the frog toward the tip.

[image: Down bow symbol]

An "up bow" — drawing the bow from tip toward the frog — is a "V"-shaped symbol.

[image: Up bow symbol]

---

IMAGES SOURCE: http://www.the-violin.com/up-and-down-bow

Comment: This notation, probably adapted from bowed instruments, is also used for the guitar, where   ⃩ stands for down picking (towards treble strings), and V upstroke (towards bass strings).

Comment: It always puzzled me that V, a downward arrow should mean Up Bow, whilst the ∏ symbol which has a line at the top means Down Bow.

Comment: @BrianTHOMAS I've heard different theories about the reason. One was that they were originally letters, with **n** denoting _nobilis_ and **v** _vilis_, which did actually not specify bowing direction as such but basically _importance_ of notes – and at some point players would be playing all weak notes with an upbow so it because synonymous. Another explanation was that they're simply icons depicting the frog and tip of a bow. Anyway on viols, cellos and basses the terms “down” and ”up” don't really apply, they just spread over from the violins.

Comment: @leftaroundabout never really thought about the fact that you don't pick/bow up/down on a cello/bass... it's sideways.. sort of :) - the first theory sounds pretty plausible though, interesting info.